# spyder won't autocomplete with new interpreter (virtualenv)

Tags: python, autocomplete, virtualenv, spyder

I apologize first that this seems identical to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spyderlib/ru61FnwZbyI). My virtualenv seems to work fine. I would just like to use spyder as an IDE to smooth over my Python deficiencies.

Following the above discussion, I changed the interpreter with 
Tools>>Preferences>>Console>>Advanced>>PythonExecutable
and I set it to /bin/python

Great! Works like a charm. However, unlike the case with the default interpreter, Spyder will not autocomplete my code. Normally I am prompted after a period for example.

'Tools>>Update module names'
did not help as was suggested.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly this problem was resolved when I installed PySide to the virutal environment. I was alerted to install PySide when I tried to call matplotlib.pyplot from within Spyder

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) I was about to answer you that but I wasn't really sure. Now I'm sure: you need PyQt4 or PySide in your virtualenv for code completion in the Python console to work. However, that's not necessary for the IPython one. You just need IPython installed in your virtualenv and run this magic `%rehashx`

Comment: For anyone having this problem with python 3.6, pyside has been replaced with pyside2.